# Display error messages in Spring login

Tags: spring, security, authentication, message

I am using Spring security for authenticating users. I created a custom authentication provider and now I am wondering how I can get error messages from the provider into my form. This is the authenticate() method in my custom authentication provider:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    UserProfile profile = userProfileService.findByEmail(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());

    if(profile == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Invalid credentials", authentication.getPrincipal()));
    }

    String suppliedPasswordHash = DigestUtils.shaHex(authentication.getCredentials().toString());

    if(!profile.getPasswordHash().equals(suppliedPasswordHash)){
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials");
    }

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(profile, null, profile.getAuthorities());

    return token;
}
```

This is my form:

```
<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
<div id="data-entry-form">

    <div class="form-entry">
        <label><spring:message code="login.form.label.email"/></label>
        <input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
    </div>
    <div class="form-entry">
        <label><spring:message code="login.form.label.password"/></label>
        <input type='password' name='j_password'/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-entry">
        <input type="submit" value="Verzenden"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I get error messages into my form? From the moment I press the login button, Spring takes over, so the only method I could generate error messages in would be the authenticate() method...

Answer (score 24):

3 Steps of the safest way (we don't rely on the LAST_EXCEPTION):

1. Specify error page (for example "login-error") in configuration for your custom authentication provider

   ```
   httpSecurity
   .authorizeRequests()
   .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**").permitAll()
   .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
   .and()
   .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
   .failureUrl("/login-error")
   .and()
   .logout().permitAll()
   ```
2. Create controller for url /login-error that returns view of your custom login page (for example "login") with the next code:

   ```
   @Controller
   public class LoginController {

       @GetMapping("/login-error")
       public String login(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
           HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
           String errorMessage = null;
           if (session != null) {
               AuthenticationException ex = (AuthenticationException) session
                       .getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
               if (ex != null) {
                   errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
               }
           }
           model.addAttribute("errorMessage", errorMessage);
           return "login";
       }
   }
   ```
3. Get the error message into your page finally (ThymeLeaf tags for example):

   ```
   <!--/*@thymesVar id="errorMessage" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
   <div class="alert" th:if="${errorMessage}" th:text="${errorMessage}"></div>
   ```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve it like this:

```
<c:if test="${param.auth eq 'failure'}">
  <div class="error">
    <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
  </div>
</c:if>
```

Note that you need to detect whether there was an error via a special parameter which you can set in your spring-security config like this:

```
<security:form-login [...] authentication-failure-url="/login?auth=failure" />
```

**EDIT:**
Actually, passing that parameter is not necessary. Instead, one can simply check whether `SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message` is defined, like this:

```
<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}">
  <div class="error">
    <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" />
  </div>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you should be able to get the messages in the same way than using the "standard" authenticators.
If an exception (or more than one) is thrown in the authentication process, the last exception is stored in a session attribute: SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.

So, to get the last exception message from the JSP you can use something like this:

```
<%=((Exception) request.getSession().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION")).getMessage()%>;
```

Of course, if you have a controller you should probably get the message from the controller and pass only the string to the jsp. This is only an example ;)

Comment: I was having lots of `NullPointerException`s in JSP with this solution, even after I added checks for every variable I was dereferencing. So I found a nicer solution and posted it as my own answer.